# How to catch exception from CloseHandle()

Tags: c++, exception

As of the MSDN spec, `CloseHandle` throws an Exception if an invalid handle is passed to it when it runs under a debugger.

Since I want to have clean code, I've inserted some code to catch it. However, it doesn't work, the exception gets uncaught.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <exception>
/* omitted code */
CloseHandle(myHandle); // close the handle, the handle is now invalid
try {
    success = CloseHandle(myHandle);
} catch (std::exception& e) {
    _tprintf(TEXT("%s\n"), e.what());
} catch (...) {
    _tprintf(TEXT("UNKNOWN\n"));
}
```

I get the following two errors from the debugger:

> First-chance exception: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.
>
> Uncaught exception: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.

I think that the first-chance exception is normal, since it gets fired before the catch statement should get it. However, the uncaught exception makes me wondering what's actually wrong here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two options:

**Option 1:**
 Use SEH, you need to write something like this:

```
__try
{
  // closeHandle
}
__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
{
  // print
}
```

**Option 2:**
Use the compiler switch /EHa, which will instruct the compiler to emmit code which will allow you to handle SEH exception via C++ style exception handling:

```
try
{
 // close handle
}
catch (...)
{
  // print
}
```

**Edit:**
Note that `CloseHandle()` only raises an exception if a debugger is attached to your process. 
From the documentation:

> If the application is running under a debugger, the function will
>   throw an exception if it receives either a handle value that is not
>   valid or a pseudo-handle value.

Comment: If it still throws this exception, even if you have __try/__except, you probably have enabled breaking on this exception. Go to menu Debug/Exceptions/Win32 Exceptions and disable option c0000008 An invalid handle was specified. After OK breaking to Visual Studio should stop.

Answer (score 3):

I guess MSDN is talking about SEH exceptions, which are not the same as C++ exceptions.

[Related MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks! What is the way to go for to get the text "An invalid handle was specified."?

0xC0000008 can be gotten via GetExceptionCode()

Comment: You may try the FormatMessage function, but I'm not sure about that one : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(VS.85).aspx